# Логический тип данных

Tags: mysql

Есть ли в MySQL логический тип данных, наподобие Access'a, чтобы ставился радиопреключатель или галочка ?

Comment: А BIT чем не устраивает?

Comment: BIT(1) будет занимать 1 байт?

Answer (score 6):

По сути - такого типа нет.
Даже выполнив:

```
ALTER TABLE  `table` CHANGE  `bool`  `bool` BOOLEAN NOT NULL
```

Тип поля будет TINYINT(1).

Замечу: при обработке запроса, при любом типе поля - **true** и **false** автоматически заменяются на **1** и **0**.

```
( Select * from `a` where `b` = true  ) == ( Select * from `a` where `b` = 1 )
```

Comment: Ну да, это BOOLEAN, BOOL это псевдонимы типов.

Answer (score 1):

И чего вы людей будоражите?

```
drop temporary table t1;
create temporary table t1(
f1 boolean -- тот же результат при TINYINT( 1 )
)
select
    34 as f1 ;

select * from t1 ;
```

-- вывод = 34 , не 1 или 0.

Answer (score 0):

Есть - BOOLEAN. Ознакомтесь:
[Типы данных](http://sevidi.ru/webd/dweb/phppage37.php)

Comment: почему же в офф доках я этого не нашел?   Интересно сколько места займет тип данных BIT(1) ? Думаю что это будет 8 бит , то есть 1 байт. в таком случае можно  использовать TINYINT(1). Сэкономить на битах не получится.(?)